# Why don't we take $r$ as equal to the radius in the spherical coordinate system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, coordinate-systems

This is a question of electrostatics from Griffiths.

> Question: Calculate the potential inside a uniformly charged solid sphere of radius $R$ and total charge $q$

In the solution manual, the answer is given as this:

[image]

I want to know why don't we take the r (in the denominator) simply as the radius for a differential equation as the distance of any point in a sphere is equal to the radius of the circle having that point.

Comment: It’s the distance from the infinitesimal element of charge $dq=\rho d\tau$ located at $(r,\theta,\phi)$ to the point where you are computing the potential it creates. All the charge of the ball is not at the origin; it is uniformly distributed throughout the ball.

Comment: *the radius for a differential equation* What does a differential equation have to do with this integral?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a right-angle triangle as $(r,\theta)$ is changing. For example, see the triangle when $\theta=\pi/2.$

They draw the right angle by mistake, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has cylindrical symmetry - the potential at $P$ will depend on the distance $z$ between $P$ and the centre of the sphere, but it will not depend on the angle by which the sphere is rotated about the axis through $P$. So cylindrical coordinates are a natural choice for framing the first integral for $V$. Griffiths then converts from cylindrical coordinates to spherical coordinates so that he can use the fact that $\rho$ takes a constant value in the region $0 \le r \le R$ i.e. within the sphere. The diagram with the right angled triangle is simply illustrating the conversion from cylindrical coordinates to spherical coordinates.